# Bash script delete file inside another folder if present in both with extension *.c

Tags: command-line, bash

Write a shell script that deletes all C sources in one directory if they are in the structure of another directory. The first argument on the command line is the directory where the C sources are located, and the second is the directory where the search starts.

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ $# -ne 2 ]
    then
        echo "for execution complete the line of command: $0 dir1 dir2"
        exit 1
fi
if [ ! d ~/$1 ]
        then
        echo "write a directory in order to do the search"
        exit 1
fi
if [ ! d ~/$2 ]
        then
        echo "write a directory in order to do the search"
        exit 1
fi
find $2 -type f -name*.c > listafis.txt
for f in listafis.txt
    do
    if grep f $1
    then rm f
    fi
done
```

This is what I have tried and it doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compare files in two directories and remove one if it exists in both places.

```
$ comm -z -12 \
  <(find folder1/ -type f -name '*.c' -printf %P\\0 | sort -z) \
  <(find folder2/ -type f -name '*.c' -printf %P\\0 | sort -z) | xargs -0 -I {} rm -i folder2/{}
```

Comment: I used this and it asks me if I want to delete the file, but I can't press y or n.

Comment: if you remove `-i` from rm will stop prompting [yN] but remember the starting-point on find cant have same name that will delete all files in the  dir supplied to rm.

Comment: Thank you very much!!